# Vue3/Nuxt3 data only available in template, not script

Tags: vuejs3, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 page with the following setup script:

```js
<script setup>
  const { data } = await useFetch('/api/entries');
  const entries = data.entries;
  console.log(entries);
</script>

<template>
{{ data.entries }} <- FINE
{{ entries }} <- NOT FINE
</template>
```

When using `data` in the template it works fine. But when trying to use `data` in the script and do some more processing it is undefined.

Is that expected behavior? If so, why and how would I continue using the `data` object?

Edit:
`useFetch` uses the event handler from the `server/[...].js` file:

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  let apiUrl = "my_api.com"

  return $fetch(`${apiUrl}${event.node.req.url}`)
})
```

Comment: Is your API external or from the server folder? Also, best practice to always wrap your dynamic content with a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

In the script part the data needs to be accessed as `data.value`. So in this case it's `data.value.entries` and not just `data.entries`. In the template part `{{ data }}` already accesses the value of the property, so `{{ data.entries }}` works there.

See: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api

Comment: Yep, the refs are unwrapped inside of the `template` tag.